# Classifying text with scikit

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm learning Scikit machine-learning for a project and while I'm beginning to grasp the general process the details are a bit fuzzy still.

Earlier I managed to build a classifier, train it and test it with test set. I saved it to disk with cPickle. Now I want to create a class which loads this classifier and lets user to classify single tweets with it.

I thought this would be trivial but I seem to get ValueError('dimension mismatch') from X_new_tfidf = *self.tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(fitTweetVec)* line with following code:

```
class TweetClassifier:

classifier = None
vect = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()

#open the classifier saved to disk to be utilized later
def openClassifier(self, name):
    with open(name+'.pkl', 'rb') as fid:
        return cPickle.load(fid)

def __init__(self, classifierName):
    self.classifier = self.openClassifier(classifierName)
    self.classifyTweet(np.array([u"Helvetin vittu miksi aina pitää sataa vettä???"]))

def classifyTweet(self, tweetText):

    fitTweetVec = self.vect.fit_transform(tweetText)
    print self.vect.get_feature_names()
    X_new_tfidf = self.tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(fitTweetVec)
    print self.classifier.predict(X_new_tfidf)
```

What I'm doing wrong here? I used similar code while I made the classifier and ran test set for it. Have I forgotten some important step here?

Now I admit that I don't fully understand yet the fitting and transforming here since I found the Scikit's tutorial a bit ambiguous about it. If someone knows an as clear explanation of them as possible, I'm all for links :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your classifier was trained with a fixed number of features (the length of the vocabulary of your previous data) and now when you `fit_transform` the new tweet, the `TfidfTransformer` will produce a new vocabulary and a new number of features, and will represent the new tweet in this space.

The solution is to also save the previously fitted `TfidfTransformer` (which contains the old vocabulary), load it with the classifier and `.transform` (not `fit_transform` because it was already fitted to the old data) the new tweet in this same representation.

You can also use a `Pipeline` that contains both the `TfidfTransformer` and the `Classifier` and pickle the `Pipeline`, this is easier and recommended.

Comment: Thanks! Got it working. Also pickling the pipeline is a good idea.